# OpenVPN: forward traffic on specific ports to client

Tags: iptables, openvpn, port-forwarding, ufw

I have an OpenVPN server on a DigitalOcean machine, and several clients connecting to it, including a Synology NAS with a mail server. I would like to use the VPN server to forward all incoming mail traffic to the client.

I have verified that:

1. the client is indeed connected to the server
2. port 25 is accessible from the server machine
3. `net/ipv4/ip_forward` is enabled in `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf`

I added the following rules to `ufw` and reloaded the firewall.

```
ufw route allow in on eth0 out on tun0 to 10.8.0.x port 25 from any
ufw allow from any to 10.8.0.x port 25
```

The `iptable` rules show the following:

```
Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.8.0.x             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             10.8.0.x             udp dpt:25

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.8.0.x             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             10.8.0.x             udp dpt:25
```

Trying to connect from the outside, the server does not respond.

```
$ telnet x.x.x.x 25                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Trying x.x.x.x...
telnet: connect to address x.x.x.x: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Any advice on where things may go wrong? Am I missing anything?

Comment: i 5hink nat is missing

Comment: I enabled NAT forwarding

Comment: then try a Look on https://askubuntu.com/questions/660972/port-forwarding-with-ufw